# Framework and Tipps for Webdevelopment (WebAR and WebVR)

Tags: javascript, web-development, web, vr, augmented-reality

im working on my bachelor thesis "three dimensional visualisation (AR and VR) in a webbrowser.
I looked throw a lot of Frameworks and APIs, but im not sure which one to use. 
I need a Framework that can work with both augmented and virtual reality, preferably markerless.
Need Collision detection ,the possibility for an walkingsimulator, and easy interaction (not so important)
The best Frameworks that i found, till now, are Babylon.js and A-Frame, in combination with ar.js.
Also found 8thwall, but i dont want to pay or rely on the website to host everything.

Im also looking into Opencv.js and its really useful and deep, but not sure to start my own groundplane tracking when there are some already working.
Would love to hear other opinion and other frameworks that works well.

Thanks and sorry for my english im from germany

Comment: Why not do a WebGL app with Unity3d ?

Comment: Hi thanks for you reply, i think Unitys WebGL is a little bit outdated, its slower and creates big files compaired to other WebGl Frameworks